# Toyota 4-runner front axle

Tags: toyota, 4wd, axle

I recently ran into a big problem with my driver side front axle on my 1995 toyota 4-runner. for some reason its not wanting to act right. I replaced the axle, bearings, rotor, sway bar, bushings and everything. For some reason the axle is still messing up, assuming its the axle itself, can I just remove it and drive it in 2 wheel drive. I don't need 4 wheel, I just need it to work. Is this okay to do?

Comment: Can you explain "not wanting to act right",do you mean won't engage,grinds,locks up?

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a seal that holds your gear oil in place on the shaft. Also, assuming you bought these online and installed yourself, did you verify them to be the same length and also that the shaft sat all the way into its seat? If it did not seat it could have wiggle room that allows it to slide in and out, instead of flex.